# A manufacturer of space shuttle light bulbs claims that the defect rate of the bulbs is $0.1\%$.

Tags: statistics

> A manufacturer of space shuttle light bulbs claims that the defect rate of the bulbs is $0.1\%$. You suspect the defect rate is actually higher, so you have checked $1000$ identical light bulbs from this manufacturer and found out that 3 of them are defect. 
>   Formulate the relevant hypotheses and test statistic (including its distribution) and investigate the claim of the manufacturer at significance level $α = 0.05$.

In my opinion, is a Binomial Distribution $Bin(1000,0.001)$. 
For the hypothesis, it's correct to assume that $H_0:\mu=0.001$, $H_1:\mu>0.001$? 
Then how can I use the significance level with a Binomial Distribution? (I know how to solve it but with a Normal) :(

For a $Bin(n,p)$ $P(X=k)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot p^k\cdot(1-p)^{n-k}$

Comment: Why not apply the normal approximation to Binomial RVs via CLT. Seems appropriate here with high $N$ and small $p$. Anyway on the wikipedia page for Binomial RVs you can find many confidence intervals for the proportion $p$. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: Won't work as the variance is too low.

Comment: You may try Poisson instead with $\lambda=1$ and calculate $1-P(X\leq3)$ easily.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe is not more accurate to use the binomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly more accurate is $H_0:μ\le 0.001, H_1:μ>0.001$. That is, the manufacturer claims an upper limit. It doesn't matter for the analysis though. We will still use the same $p=0.001$.

We need to calculate $P(X\ge 3)$ to verify the hypothesis. If it is less than $\alpha=0.05$ we can reject the manufacturer's claim. We can find it with:
$$P(X\ge 3)=1-P(X<3)=1-\big[P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)\big]$$

Comment: Now is clear, thank you!

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $P(X>3)$?

Comment: No @MichaelHoppe, we found 3 broken bulbs. We want to know if that (or more) can happen with a reasonable probability.

Comment: If not we can tell the manufacturer that we are >95% sure that his claim is false.